# Coloring bars with different colors 'manually' or using a logical expression in pandas barplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart

I want to color bars representing values that exceed a numeric value and which relate to a certain interval of years in a timeseries with different color from the rest.

My first attempt to do it 'manually' --i.e., by prescribing manually the color for each bar in the plot-- resulted in an exception. I would like to know how to correct the code and also if there is a way to automate the coloring using a logical expression.

My data are:

```
df1

2004    23
2005    10
2006     2
2007    15
2008    13
2009    15
2010    30
2011    38
2012    42
2013    72

my_colors = 'b'*6 + 'r'*4
my_colors # I want bars representing values above 15 and after 2005 to be colored 
          # red, while the rest blue
'bbbbbbrrrr' 
df1.plot(kind = 'bar', color = my_colors, figsize = (10, 8))
plt.title('Immigration from Iceland to Canada')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Number of Immigrants')
plt.show()

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'bbbbbbrrrr'
```

Answer (score 0):

lets suppose you have column called 
Value which contains those numerical values and Date for those dates

```
a = (df['Value'] > 15)& (df['Date'] > 2005)

colors = np.where(a, 'r', 'b')
print(colors)

['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'r' 'r' 'r' 'r']
```

Now You can use this color in your plot

```
color = colors
```